# How do you log-out of retrocomputing ?, and, there are problems with the text-editor for writing questions?

Tags: support, formatting, login

How do you log-out of retrocomputing ?

and,

There are problems with the text-editor for writing questions, it does not allow you to satisfactorily put line-breaks and indent text how you want it, which severely affects how you want to present your question

( I assume I should send this to admin, so it may not be allowed as a question, but this way maybe people can post opinions )

Comment: You can never truly log out of retrocomputing. Once you get bitten by the retrocomputing bug, there is no escape! As for logging out of the StackExchange system, there is probably a button somewhere - I've never looked for it. The text editor is actually pretty good - a variant of markdown. Take a look at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Click on the Stackexchange icon on the top right (hover text: a list of all 172 Stack Exchange Sites) and then choose log out.

Comment: That's where the log out button is, thanks ,  I will take a look at  https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting regarding the text-editor which so far I think is below average

Comment: @texttext What are you expecting from the text editor that isn't there?

Comment: There probably is a correct thread for these issues on Stackexchange somewhere,  don't know

Comment: It's not great that some comments( those after 5 comments ) on these threads are hidden, until you press the link to show them,  I'm particularly thinking in the case of new members on the site, who may not have noticed that,  and may miss some comments, even though they are notified on the top-right, although yes I know the admin has to balance advantages with disadvantages

Answer (score 3):

To log out of any StackExchange site, click on the "hamburger" icon in the top right of the screen.

[image: Screen grab of logout button]

There you will find the log out button.

As you note in a comment, the guide to formatting is on the Main Meta 
[here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting)
Like any text editor, you can put in line breaks and tabs once you know the tricks.

Some sites have additional formatting features, specific to common posts on those sites.  Beta sites such as ours do not.

Answer (score 1):

> There are problems with the text-editor for writing questions

The text editor uses [Markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You are limited to what it will let you do, but it is quite a good trade off between power and simplicity. There's no way I know of to do indents, but you can do block quotes, indent lists and code blocks. For example, the block quote at the top of my answer is done like this:

```
> There are problems with the text-editor for writing questions
```